# What's the easiest workaround on the OS, which doesn't have the dup2 syscall?

Tags: c, unix, posix, system-calls, xv6

I'm working with the xv6 OS and I need to substitute `stdio` with a file. This is normally done with the `dup2` syscall, which this OS doesn't have. Is there any workaround? Do I have to implement my own syscall which will try to mimic the POSIX's one behavior? Or can the functionality I need (substitute the file descriptor) can be implemented in a regular function in a c program? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it has the `dup()` call. Which can be used to do the same.

Comment: @EugeneSh. how so? `dup` returns a free alias to already existing file descriptor. What I'm actually trying to do, is to substitute `stdio` with a file

Comment: Since it has `dup`, it uses fds. On that system, does opening a new fd use the lowest available? If so, and if you mean fd 0, 1 or 2 when you say `stdio`, just close the one you want to replace before using `dup`

Comment: If you close `stdin` before, then its descriptor will be assigned to the `dup`-ed one - as it will be the lowest one available.

Comment: [Standard `freopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~junfeng/11sp-w4118/lectures/unix.pdf for some examples

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dup2( filedes, filedes2 );
```

means

```
close( filedes2 );
fcntl( filedes, F_DUPFD, filedes2 );
```

You can do

```
close(0);
dup(fd);
```

subject to race conditions, since dup2 atomic function but close and dup include two function calls.

Comment: Because of the race condition in a multithreaded program, it'd be wise to check that the return from `dup` or `fcntl(fd, F_DUPFD, filedes2)` is the file descriptor you expect.